# Line up floating div above Kendo Chart Bars

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, css-float

I'm trying to line up a series of floating `div` elements above corresponding columns in a kendo chart so that it looks something like the below

[image: desired result]

I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach but this is what I've got so far.

Kendo charts are rendered using SVG and I can use the `getBBox()` method to get the boundary box for the bar.

```
var kChartData = $("#myChart").data("kendoChart");
var columnBoundingBox = kChartData.element
    .find("g:first")
    .find("g:first")
    .children("g")
    .eq(3)
    .find("g:first")
    .children("g")[i]
    .getBBox();
```

This gives me the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` coordinates of the **bar** in the bar chart.

I thought I could use the `x` coordinate of each bar to set the `left` property of my floating `div` elements but it doesn't seem to work. There seems to be some kind of offset preventing it from lining up properly.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: What does it look like currently? would appreciate a jsFiddle demo

Comment: Have you thought about just adding SVG elements to the chart: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/onALe

Comment: @ezanker wow this is amazing. This is pretty much exactly what I'd like to achieve. Please post this as an answer and I'll give you full marks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add SVG elements to the chart. One way is to use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.visual)** of the series to draw the extra shapes as well as the bars:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    theme: "flat",
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column",
        visual: function (e) {
            var origin = e.rect.origin;
            var center = e.rect.center();
            var bottomRight = e.rect.bottomRight();
            var topRight = e.rect.topRight();
            var topLeft = e.rect.topLeft();
            var c = e.options.color;  

            var path = new kendo.drawing.Path({
                fill: {color:  c,opacity: 1,},
                stroke: {color: c,opacity: 0.7,width: 2,}
            })
            .moveTo(origin.x, bottomRight.y)
            .lineTo(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
            .lineTo(topRight.x, topRight.y)
            .lineTo(topLeft.x, topLeft.y)
            .close();

            if (e.value > 40) c = "rgb(124,200,124)";

            var path2 = new kendo.drawing.Path({
                fill: {color:  c,opacity: 1,},
                stroke: {color: c,opacity: 0.7,width: 2,}
            })
            .moveTo(origin.x, 18)
            .lineTo(bottomRight.x, 0)
            .lineTo(topRight.x, 18)
            .lineTo(topLeft.x, 0)
            .close();

            var position = new kendo.geometry.Point(center.x, 24);
            var text = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.value + "%", position, {
              fill: {color:  "rgba(0,0,0,0.999)",}
            });

            var group = new kendo.drawing.Group();
            group.append(path, path2);
            group.append(text);
            return group;
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: "Total Visits",
        data: [10, 30, 20, 45, 60]
    }, ],
    panes: [{
        clip: false
    }],
    valueAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
        line: {
            visible: false
        },
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
    },
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"],
        majorGridLines: {
            visible: false
        },
        line: {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true
    },
    render: function(e){
      $('[fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.999)"]').attr("text-anchor", "middle");
    }
});
```

### **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/onALe)**

NOTE: I am using the **[render event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#events-render)** to find the added text and center it. I set the text fill to a unique color so it would be easy to select and set the text-anchor attribute.